# 'If' statement fails within batch file 'for' loop

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, batch-file

I need help to create a BAT file to do the following:

for each file in `c:\Test` check if the file name meets this format `FILE_NAME_nnnnnn_nnnn.txt` where `n` must be random characters.

```
If true:
Execute command 1
execute command 2
execute command 3
Else:
Execute command 4
```

for example, let´s say I have these 4 Files in directory:

```
C:\Test\FILE_NAME_123456_1234.txt
C:\Test\FILE_blablaNAME_123456_1234.txt
C:\Test\FILE_NAME_1234_1234.txt
C:\Test\otherfile.txt
```

my BAT should run command `1`, `2` and `3` for `C:\Test\FILE_NAME_123456_1234.txt`, and only command `4` for the other 3 files.

I did try with the `FOR` command, but I can't make it work.

```batch-file
for %%f in (C:\test\*.*) do (
    if %%f="FILE_NAME_??????_????.txt" (
        command1
        command2
        command3
    ) else (
        command4
    )
)
```

Comment: `do (echo %%f|findstr /xi "FILE_NAME_......_.....txt" && ( cmd1 cmd2 cmd3) || ( cmd4 )`, where `.` is the `findstr` wildcard for "any character". If you need numbers only, it's `[0123456789}` for each `.` (or `[0-9]` with some caveats). See [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for the conditional parameters `&&` and `||`

Comment: @Stephan is correct; the `if` comparator in batch doesn't do regular expression or glob matching. As he explains, you'll need `findstr` for that.